# Python appending numbers on a series

Tags: python

I have this code and i need to make a list with prime numbers but i dont know why my program is not appending the prime numbers to the list. Thanks

```
n = int(input(""))
L = []
x = 0
c = 0

while x <= n - 1:
    Numero = int(input(""))
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if(n % i == 0):
            c += 1
    if c != 2:
        x += 1
    else:
        L.append(Numero)
        x += 1
print(L)
```

Comment: You must initialize `c` to 0 in each iteration of the `while` loop. Otherwise it keeps growing and never becomes 2 again.

Comment: Tried but didnt work

Comment: What is the point of entering `Numero`, if you never use it in your computation? But, most importantly, `if(n % i == 0)` must be `if(x % i == 0)`.

Comment: If "Numero" is prime then append Numero to L i use Numero in the last part because if the number is prime i append the number to L

Answer (score 0):

Short code review:

```
while x <= n - 1:  # x < n is more comprehensive than x <= n-1
                   # Also, semantically it should be "for" loop
    # As DYZ mentioned, you need to reinitialize c at every iteration
    Numero = int(input("")) # I guess it's an error since you never use it
    for i in range(1, n + 1):  # it's ok to stop once c > 2
                               # also, you only need to check up to x/2
                               # and since we know it'll match 1 and x, 
                               #     whole loop can be replaced by all()
        if(n % i == 0):  # as DYZ mentioined, it should be x % i
            c += 1

    if c != 2:
        x += 1  # this statement is executed regardless of condition
    else:
        L.append(Numero)  # I guess you mean L.append(x)
        x += 1
```

After fixing all these issues we get something like:

```
for x in range(2, n+1):
    if all(x%i != 0 for i in range(2, x/2+1)):
        L.append(x)
```

Or, as a list comprehension (note that now we're only checking if it's divisible by discovered primes - a major improvement in complexity):

```
[L.append(x) for x in range(2, n+1) if all(x%i != 0 for i in L)]
```

For `n==22` we get:

```
>>> print L
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```